# Getting the index of a part of an array element

Tags: arrays, ruby, search

I have an array like:

```
array = ["username=stackoverflow", "password=12345", "id= 6"]
```

My wish is searching for `" id "` in `array`, and get the index of `" id=6"` element, which is `2`.

Is that possible? How can I get the index of a part of an array element?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: `[ username=stackoverflow, password=12345, id= 6]` is not valid ruby syntax. Please can you provide a valid code sample? Without it, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Is this an array or a hash? Your syntax looks wrong.

Comment: For example, maybe that should be `["username=stackoverflow", "password=12345", "id=6"]`? Or `["stackoverflow", "12345", "6"]`? Or `{username:"stackoverflow", password: "12345", id: 6}`?

Comment: Also, the "index of the `"id=6"` element" (if that is actually an array) is **2**, not 3. Indexes start at 0.

Comment: Im sorry guys Im working and my brain wants to take rest. I edited.

Comment: @Stefan My answer is wrong, I deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = ["username=stackoverflow", "password=12345", "id= 6"]
array.index{ |i| i["id"] }
#=> 2
array.index{ |i| i["non-existing"] }
#=> nil
```

`index` accept either a block or an element and will return an index of an element in the array or the index of the first truthy predicate application.

```
array.index("id= 6")
#=> 2
```

In our case, we use a block as a predicate. This block will be applied to all elements in the array. The block looks like `i["id"]` which is a shorthand for getting a substring "id" in the string. So we are looking for the first element with an "id" substring in it.

As comments below mentioned, you can have some false positives with the curent approach. For example a string "username=Midas" also has `id` substring, so you would better use a more strict pattern like `i[/^id=/]` (thx @Stefan) to identify only those strings which start with "id=" substring.

Comment: While this is correct. It is definitely worth giving an explanation as to what is going on here.

Comment: Finding the index of the first string which contains `id` might return a false positive. It would probably be safer to search for `/^id=/`.

Comment: @Stefan it depends, I'm trying not to assume anything else but `My wish is searching like " id " in that array`

Comment: @DickieBoy sure

Comment: You _are_ assuming something: that "an array like" the OP has will never contain something like `"username=Midas"`.

Comment: @fl00r and despite the OP's explicit wish to search for `" id "`, you've used `"id"` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, ah you!

Comment: @Amadan sure, valid, but unless author doesn't specify some exact pattern, I would stick to my answer and give some freedom to play around :P

Answer (score 1):

An array has no information about the names of the variables you use to initialize the array. An array just stores the values.

Use an [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) instead that allows you to store key and values:

```
hash = { username: 'stackoverflow', password: 12345, id: 6 }
hash[:id]
#=> 6
```

Comment: The OP needed help getting the index from an array. Not the value of one of the attributes in a hash.

Comment: But actually my goal is reach the value. I did not know that is hash is. I will search and try thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [ "username=stackoverflow", "password=12345", "id= 6"]
array.find_index { |e| e.split(/\s*=\s*/)[0] == 'id' }
```

This will split each element by the equals sign, possibly surrounded by whitespace, and return the index if the first part of the split is `'id'`. If you want to do this repeatedly, it would almost certainly be better to transform this into a structure that is easier to look up, such as hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.to_enum.with_index.find{|e, _| e.match?(/id/)}.last
# => 2
```